# RMI needs java.rmi.server.hostname for NAT, so what's the way other technology like CORBA to resolve NAT issue?

Tags: java, rmi, corba, hosts

In Java, if client needs to open connection to RMI server, we need to specify **-Djava.rmi.server.hostname=hostxxx** to server's startup parameter, 
and add hosts entry to client's hosts file like below:

```
x.x.x.x  hostxxx
```

As every client need to add the hosts entry, it is inconvenitent to do so.

I am just wondering what's the way CORBA (or other RPC solution) to resolve this issue?
should they also need to modify hosts entry like RMI?

Answer (score 0):

That system property is only for RMI/JRMP. I'm not aware of any way to do it for CORBA, and I've looked.

Comment: from this pdf, http://pdf.aminer.org/000/523/991/evaluation_of_three_approaches_for_corba_firewall_nat_traversal.pdf, CORBA needs to deploy a proxy to address NAT/firewall issue, seems more complex than RMI.